# Return a List of present objects from a List of Optional objects using Lightweight-Stream-API

Tags: java, android, lightweight-stream-api

Consider I have an array list of `Optional` objects like `List<Visit> visit = {Optional[Visit], Optional[Visit], ...}`. How do i get the `Visit` object from the `Optional` and just return those objects as a `List`?

I tried something like this:

```java
return Stream.of(visits).filter(value -> Optional.isPresent(value))
    .map((Visit t) -> Optional.get(t))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and this:

```java
return Stream.of(visits)
   .map(visit -> Optional.of(visit).get())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this doesn't compile.

I am trying to use [Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) as the stream library.

Comment: Your version is actually fine so long as you can extract it into a separage function. You can use `flatMap`, of course, but I would suggest refactoring your code to replace `List<Optional<Visit>>` with `List<Visit>`.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because there is no static method `Optional.isPresent(Object)`. Both `isPresent` and `get` are instance methods. It is also not clear what are you trying to do by calling `Optional.of(t).get()` - this code is almost pointless since there is a lot cleaner and readable way to throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Let me try to explain properly what am trying to achieve. i call response. getVisits() from a method after an API call. and the return type is List<Visit> but each Visit object within the list is wrapped with an Optional. So am basically trying to get the value from the optional and add them to a new List which just contains Visits without the optional.

Comment: @irobotxxx I was going to write a simpler answer, but what is the type of `visits`?  I seemed to be confused whether it is `List<Visit>` or `List<Optional<Visit>>`

Comment: @JacobG. please see my comment above. its basically List<Visit> but in the list i have [Optional [Visit] ].

Comment: Okay, I assume you didn't specify a generic type, so it's actually a `List<Optional<Visit>>`.  Harmlezz's answer should work perfectly fine for you.

Comment: @irobotxxx, if it's `List<Visit>`, then objects can't be "wrapped" into an optional, because then it would be `List<Optional<Visit>>`. I would also insist that you should rather change code so it _doesn't_ wrap into an optional. There is no purpose in this data structure (list of optionals) apart from making developers angry and confused.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov i would agree with you on that one. I must have done something wron when mapping from the api response to my domain response. Am really sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @irobotxxx, if your API responds with optionals, you should unwrap them as soon as possible. There is a handy method `ifPresent` that you can use like this: `optional.ifPresent(myList::add)`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yeah.you are right.  that was the problem. i did it a bit too late which caused the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do it this way:

```
return visits.stream()
             .map(visit -> visit.orElse(null))
             .filter(Objects::nonNull)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Assuming `visits` is of type `List<Optional<Visit>>`.

**Causes Of Your Code Not Compiling**

Assuming that the variable `visits` is of type `List<Optional<Visit>>` the statement you posted:

```
Stream.of(visits).filter(value -> Optional.isPresent(value))
                 .map((Visit t) -> Optional.get(t))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

has the following problems:

1. `Stream.of()` takes either one element or many elements of type `T` and creates a *Stream*. You use `visits` as one element of type `List<Optional<Visit>>` and I think you intend to get a *Stream* of `Optional<Visit>` which you may achieve by using `visits.stream()`.
2. `filter(value -> Optional.isPresent(value))` does invoke `isPresent(T t)` in a static way while the method `isPresent(T t)` doesn't exist, neither statically nor as an instance method. I think what you intend to do is: `filter(value -> value.isPresent())` which is equal to `filter(Optional::isPresent)`. The difference of the second is that `Optional::isPresent` does not invoke a static method but results in a method reference.
3. `map((Visit) t -> Optional.get(t))` does as well invoke a method `get(T t)` in a static way which doesn't exist, neither statically nor as an instance method. I think you intended to invoke `map((Visit) t -> t.get())` which is equal to `map(Optional::get)`.

Fixing those issues would result in the new statement:

```
visits.stream().filter(Optional::isPresent)
               .map(Optional::get)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The difference to my solution is only that you map after filter. As a reader to get it right you need to remember that `Optional::get` will always return a *non-null* value. If you map first and filter second you do not have to remember there are no `null` values because you filter them out in the second step.

Comment: Thanks for the response but could you please view my comments above to clarify what am trying to do

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Am still getting into grips with  the new Java 8 API features. Am marking these as the accepted answer, Also because of the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it as follows:

```
List<Visit> visitsWithoutOptionals = visits.stream()
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```